# SUSE Linux 12 - configuring IP alias

Tags: ip, alias, sles

I want to setup an IP address alias on a network card. I created a file `/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-ens160` and its contents are:

```
BOOTPROTO='static'
STARTMODE='onboot'
IPADDR='192.168.0.113'
NETMASK='255.255.255.0'
BROADCAST=''
ETHTOOL_OPTIONS=''
MTU=''
NAME=''
NETWORK=''
REMOTE_IPADDR=''
IPADDR_0='192.168.0.194'
NETMASK_0='255.255.255.0'
LABEL_0='0'
```

Restarted network using `systemctl restart network.service`. Still when I do `ifconfig -a` I do not get IP address from alias (IPADDR_0) only it shows IP address mentioned in `IPADDR`.

When I do individual interface restart:

```
ifdown ens160:0
ifdown: no matching interfaces

ifup ens160
wicked: No valid configuration files found at /etc/wicked/ifconfig
ifup: no matching interfaces
```

But I notice that pings to both IP address works. It just that it does not showup in the list when I give ifconfig -a.

I suspect that I have to create a config file in /etc/wicked/ifconfig to get this listed in ifconfig -a. Is there any way to detect if IP alias is set other than `ifconfig -a`.

Comment: I know that following ifconfig command - "ifconfig ens160:0 192.168.0.194" lists the ip alias in ifconfig command. But I am looking into persisting it. I have also configured the ip alias setting via Yast, it gives me identical config file but the results in ifconfig -a does not show the ip alias.

Answer (score 2):

First, I know that there will be a new image release this week or next week, hoping that you can get the latest image to retest again.

Second, instead of restarting the `network.service`, you should perform the following command:

```
wicked ifreload ens160
```

or if this is the first run:

```
wicked ifup ens160
```

`ifconfig` is obsolete. Use `iproute2` instead:

```
ip addr show
ip a s
```

both of those are equivalent

```
wicked: No valid configuration files found at /etc/wicked/ifconfig
```

This is irrelevant here. Wicked supports `ifcfg` type of configuration files and looks for them in `/etc/sysconfig/network` directory.  The above means that there is no native wicked configuration source in
`/etc/wicked/ifconfig` which is the default case at the moment - no error.

Third, regarding the rest:

```
ifdown ens160:0
ifdown: no matching interfaces
```

`ens160:0` is also obsolete syntax. There is no more aliases usage. IP addresses are applied to the same interface (please see `ip a s` command output).

```
ifup ens160
wicked: No valid configuration files found at /etc/wicked/ifconfig
ifup: no matching interfaces
```

Please run the following to see the reason:

```
wicked --debug all ifup ens160
```

Comment: "`ens160:0` is also obsolete syntax." <- It was remarkably difficult to hunt down this particular factoid.  upvotes++

Answer (score 0):

In SLES 12 `wicked` supports configs in `ifcfg-*` style but aliases need to be set in this manner (`192.168.0.113` is the primary ip address and it should contains suffix too (`_0` in this case)):

```
BOOTPROTO='static'
STARTMODE='onboot'
IPADDR_0='192.168.0.113'
NETMASK_0='255.255.255.0'
IPADDR_1='192.168.0.194'
NETMASK_1='255.255.255.0'
```

or

```
BOOTPROTO='static'
STARTMODE='onboot'
IPADDR_0='192.168.0.113/24'
IPADDR_1='192.168.0.194/24'
```

instead of creating `ifcfg-*:<alias_suffix>` configs.